# With the new Azure service bus SDK (7.0.0), what's the proper way to create a topic, subscription, and authorization rule?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I'm using Python 3.8 and the new Azure SDK for Python, specifically the azure-mgmt-servicebus 7.0.0 version.  With my previous version, whenever I needed to create a service bus topic, subscription, and appropriate authorization rule, I could do

```
sb_client = self._get_sb_client()
    authorization_rule_rights = [AccessRights.listen]
    sb_client = self._get_sb_client()
    sb_client.topics.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, parameters=TOPIC_PARAMS)
    sb_client.subscriptions.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, 
        SB_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, parameters=SUBSCRIPTION_PARAMS)

    # Create auth rule
    sb_client.topics.create_or_update_authorization_rule(
        resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
        namespace_name=namespace_name,
        topic_name=topic_name,
        authorization_rule_name=SB_SAS_POLICY_LISTEN,
        parameters=authorization_rule_rights)
```

However, with the new SDK, my "create_or_update_authorization_rule" now throws a

```
   msrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

error.  The new documentation -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus?view=azure-python#service-bus-topics-and-subscriptions, does not detail how to create the topics, only send a message using an existing topic.  With the newest SDK, what's the proper way to create the topic, subscription, and authorization rule?

Comment: where do you find the version 7.0.0 of azure-mgmt-servicebus? I can see the latest version is [6.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicebus/).

Comment: Dave, you mixed up azure-servicebus (which went 7.0.0 last week and is about sending SB messages) and azure-mgmt-servicebus (which went 6.0.0 last week and is about creating/managing SB account). I would encourage you clarify your title and question to focus on the 6.0.0 of azure-mgmt-servicebus, and leave azure-servicebus out of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the latest version of [azure-mgmt-servicebus is 6.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicebus/).

To create authorization rule, you should put the value of `authorization_rule_rights` in a `json` format.

Here is an example:

```
       authorization_rule_rights= {
          "rights": [
            "Listen",
            "Send"
          ]
        }

        result = sb_client.topics.create_or_update_authorization_rule(
                   resource_group_name=RESOURCE_GROUP, 
                   namespace_name=NAMESPACE_NAME, 
                   topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, 
                   authorization_rule_name=AUTHORIZATION_RULE_NAME, 
                   parameters=authorization_rule_rights)
```

For more details about authorization rule creation, you can refer to [this doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-mgmt-servicebus/tests/test_cli_mgmt_servicebus_topic.py#L152).

For the topic creation, refer to [this section](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-mgmt-servicebus/tests/test_cli_mgmt_servicebus_topic.py#L56).

For subscription creation, refer to [this section](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-mgmt-servicebus/tests/test_cli_mgmt_servicebus_topic.py#L64).