# Azure ServiceBus: created Shared Access Policy for queue programmatically

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I need to create some entities in Azure ServiceBus using Python.

Creating a *Queue* works like a charm:

```py
adminClient.create_queue('<name>', default_message_time_to_live='P8D', uplicate_detection_history_time_window='PT1H', lock_duration='PT1M', max_delivery_count=100, max_size_in_megabytes=4096, max_message_size_in_kilobytes=256)
```

The Queue gets created without a *Shared access policy*, so I want to achieve that in code as well:

```py
adminClient.create_queue('<name>', authorization_rules=[ AuthorizationRule(type='SharedAccessPolicy',key_name='...',rights=[ 'Send' ]) ], default_message_time_to_live='P8D', uplicate_detection_history_time_window='PT1H', lock_duration='PT1M', max_delivery_count=100, max_size_in_megabytes=4096, max_message_size_in_kilobytes=256)
```

Running this code throws `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: SubCode=50000. Internal Server Error`. I don't even know if `SharedAccessPolicy` is correct as `type`. I tried adding `primary_Key='...'` and `secondary_key='...'`, but got the same result.

I am aware of the documentation found at https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/azure.servicebus.management.html#azure.servicebus.management.AuthorizationRule, but it doesn't really help.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try with `Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces/AuthorizationRules` for type?

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! Nope, same result. 

Just out of curiosity: how did you come up with this type and this hierarchy? I am asking because this cannot be found anywhere else in the Python API.

Comment: I looked at the REST API documentation.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65103812/188096.

Comment: I just learned that there is `azure.servicebus.management` (which I am on) and there is `azure.mgmt.servicebus`: two different packages, different versions, different API. I need to check and get back :-|

Comment: I am giving up on this: `azure.mgmt.servicebus` seems to be a really thin layer on top of the REST API: it keeps giving me weird messages, the documentation is lousy, I've lost the fun of it.

@GauravMantri : thank you so much for your help, highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I have used `azure.mgmt.servicebus` from `azure-mgmt-servicebus` package.

For reference check this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-mgmt-servicebus/generated_samples).

##### My Code:

**`app.py`:**

```py
from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
sub_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
resource_group = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential=credentials,subscription_id=sub_id)

#create queue
client.queues.create_or_update(resource_group,"pysdksb","sdkqueue",parameters={"properties":{"enablePartitioning": True}})

# create an authorization rules in created queue.
client.queues.create_or_update_authorization_rule(resource_group,"pysdksb","sdkqueue",authorization_rule_name="sdkauth",
        parameters={"properties": {"rights": ["Listen", "Send"]}},)

print("Queue created with Shared Access Policy.")
```

#### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

[image]